# Получить данные из примера кода, в котором используется return

Tags: python

У меня есть пример кода с github, в котором запрашиваются данные с api одного сайта. Они используют class, потом много раз def для разных запросов и после каждого def, функцию return.

Как мне, наконец, увидеть те данные? Я не пользовался return, когда работал с другим сайтом, только print, и он выводил все, что мне нужно на экран.

Как и где мне дописать print, чтобы данные появились и их можно было прочитать?

Или как для этого использовать return?

Пример кода:

```
class Client:
    ...
    def info(self):
        return self._public_api_call('info')
```

В этом репозитории есть тест файл, где проверяют работу данной функции с помощью функции assert. Все работает. Мне интересен вывод на экран. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну так тупо перед ретурн написать строку с принт

Comment: Вызовите метод `info()` и напечатайте результат.

Answer (score 4):

Создать объект `Client` и вызвать у него метод `info`:

```
client = Client()
print(client.info())

info = client.info()
print(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто в `print` у класса `Client` вызвать метод `info`.

```
print(Client().info())
```